# Strange merge() behavior in Hibernate as quoted in Hibernate reference

Tags: hibernate

In the hibernate reference it is said that merge()

> • if there is no persistent instance currently associated with the
>   session, try to load it from the database, or create a new persistent
>   instance
>
> • the persistent instance is returned
>
> • the given instance does not become associated with the session, it
>   remains detached

what does the last line mean that the returned object is detached? merge() is used for re associating detach object with the session, so how come it is returning detached object?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says "given instance". This means:

```
A a, b;
...
a = session.merge( b );
```

At this stage, `a` is associated with the session but `b` remains detached.